# Get zoom value from google maps encoded string

Tags: google-maps, zooming, polygon, geospatial

I have a page which displays different polygons saved as strings in SQL Db. I managed to center the map depending on the polygon being loaded, but I would also like to set the zoom level of the map, depending on the polygon's zoom level. I have seen many discussions on this topic (i.e. [How can I get zoom levels to decode a polyline from Google Maps Directions API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653483/how-can-i-get-zoom-levels-to-decode-a-polyline-from-google-maps-directions-api)), but I am nowhere nearer the solution. Could anyone help?

I center the map using coordinates, which I get from decodePath method,

```
google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(googlePolygon)
```

however it only returns lat long values, without any levels or zoom level information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the path returned from `google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(googlePolygon)` to create a bounds object for it, then use `google.maps.Map.fitBounds` with that bounds.

```
var polyPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(googlePolygon);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i=0; i < polyPath.length; i++) {
  bounds.extend(polyPath[i]);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```