# How to draw and navigate routes on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, coordinates

I want to draw routes on Google Maps (walk or drive), I want to give intent the current user coordinates and the destination coordinates, to draw and navigate the route, as this image

[image]

I used this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345")); startActivity(intent);
```

but I got "No route found"

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with intent. You should use JSON request with `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters.` If you use JSON request, you must make it like this example, just add your coordinates : `String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="yourlat","yourlong"&destination="secondlat","secondlong"&sensor=false";`

This may help: [Android draw route on a Mapview with twoo POI-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408671/android-draw-route-on-a-mapview-with-twoo-poi-s) and this [How do I draw a KML file on a MapView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845790/how-do-i-draw-a-kml-file-on-a-mapview-in-android)