# Is possible to get street name in route

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to know streets's name taken from a route provided by Google Maps API V2 Android.

I have been reading Maps Api but i don't find solution.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could geolocate the coordinates provided as each point along the route using the maps geolocation api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

This would provide you the full address of each point along your route.

*Edit*. The only other way I can think of would be to use Google Turn by Turn directions: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Steps which will obviously give you the steps to follow the route involved (involving street names), but I thought using turn by turn directions within an android app was against the TOS (I could be wrong on that) due to direct competition with Google own Maps app.

*Edit* Take a look at this similar question: [Highlight a specified route on Google Maps v2 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760723/highlight-a-specified-route-on-google-maps-v2-android) If you read the code posted in the first answer he is iterating through all of the points along the route and using them to build a polyline. With a simple geocode inserted this would achieve what you're looking for.

*Edit* In fact looking at the response, it already contains the name of each road along the route as part of the response from the API.

Comment: I need to slide every point of my route?

Comment: What do you mean by slide?

Comment: take one by one the route points

Comment: Presuming you want the street names for each route point, and not just a single street name (which I can't see being of use).

Comment: Using google maps how can I take all the points of the path?

Comment: Inspect the result of the directions request (which I presume you have got working), contained within are multiple way points. Iterate through these to get your points.

Comment: only these points not enough for me I need the name of all roads