# Drawing actual bus routes polyline Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, polyline, google-polyline

I'm doing an Android app which has a Google map in it. The main function of the app is to return a route between two locations, traveled by bus. However, the polyline returned by google direction api service for bus are just straight lines between bus stops, is there any way I can get the actual bus travelling routes? I have read stuffs and the only solution I found is to draw polyline **snap** to road, but it is not guaranteed that the bus actually travel using that road.

For example, if I request for a bus route between London Kings Cross station and London Waterloo station, and let's say this is my direction request URL:
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=LondonKingsCross&destination=LondonWaterloo&mode=transit&transit_mode=bus&key=MY_API_KEY
Then I use the JSON result to draw my polyline, it would look something like this:
[Zoomed in section of a polyline between two bus stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltTR8.png)

However, the bus might actually travel like this:
[Actual bus route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE8hv.png)

How/Where can I get the actual polyline(list of latlng points) that allows me to draw on my map?

Comment: I had a similar problem. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924834/decoding-polyline-with-new-google-maps-api

Comment: you can try this on   https://github.com/ErNaveen/Google-Directions-Android

Comment: @Fustigador Sorry I think you misunderstand my problem. I do not have problem parsing, decoding the points and drawing the polyline.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below link. Worked for me.
[Draw Path using Json Response](http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/)

Comment: This is the basic code for getting direction and drawing polylines between locations. However this does not fix my bus route problem.