# PolyUtil decoding differences between JavaScript and Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have multiple points corresponding to a route in PolyUtil encoding. I show this route in a web and in native android app, the issue is that in my web it is shown correctly but in my android app it displays a little different.

I logged both PolyUtil decodings and the points decoded are different. Using PolyUtil interactive site i get the correct route. I think the issue is with android library.

**PolyUtil encoded points:**

```
lvzsEhgvuI~c@HbJr@lJ`@|MrDfJlE~GxCdEvQ~IhCfDh@bIi@dGwB|D{GL{VqBqGcHcEeNGqGpGmHnQ
```

**android points decoded:**

```
-34.88199, -56.15223
-34.883770000000005, -56.152280000000005
-34.885600000000004, -56.15254
-34.88799, -56.152710000000006
-34.889790000000005, -56.15361000000001
-34.89123, -56.15464000000001
-34.89222, -56.15541
-34.893980000000006, -56.15841
-34.89482, -56.1591
-34.896440000000005, -56.159310000000005
-34.89775, -56.1591
-34.898700000000005, -56.158500000000004
-34.898770000000006, -56.15708000000001
-34.8982, -56.15326
-34.89674, -56.15189
-34.894310000000004, -56.15091
-34.89294, -56.150870000000005
-34.89143, -56.152240000000006
-34.891290000000005, -56.15520000000001
```

**web points decoded:**

```
-34.876070000000006,-56.152370000000005
-34.88199,-56.152420000000006
-34.883770000000005,-56.152680000000004
-34.885600000000004,-56.15285000000001
-34.88799,-56.15375
-34.889790000000005,-56.15478
-34.89123,-56.155550000000005
-34.89222,-56.158550000000005
-34.893980000000006,-56.159240000000004
-34.89482,-56.15945000000001
-34.896440000000005,-56.159240000000004
-34.89775,-56.158640000000005
-34.898700000000005,-56.15722
-34.898770000000006,-56.153400000000005
-34.8982,-56.15203
-34.89674,-56.151050000000005
-34.894310000000004,-56.15101000000001
-34.89294,-56.15238000000001
-34.89143,-56.15534
```

**in my web i decode like this:**

```
google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_estimated_wp);
```

[image: Web preview]

**in android app i decode like this:**

```
PolyUtil.decode(encoded_path);
```

[image: Android preview]

How can i fix the android route? It is shown incorrectly.

Comment: One clue for me is the first point in the web decode list is not present in the android decode list (ignoring the fractional differences for the moment) and the last point in the android decode list is not present in the web decode list.  And both have the same number of points.  This is hard to reconcile unless one suspects the string.  How does the `encoded_path` in your android code get populated and post the code which logs the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code like:

```
List <LatLng> pathPoints = PolyUtil.decode("lvzsEhgvuI~c@HbJr@lJ`@|MrDfJlE~GxCdEvQ~IhCfDh@bIi@dGwB|D{GL{VqBqGcHcEeNGqGpGmHnQ");
for (LatLng point : pathPoints) {
    Log.d(TAG, "" + point.latitude + "," + point.longitude);
}
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .addAll(pathPoints)
        .color(Color.RED)
        .width(20);
```

decode polyline

```
lvzsEhgvuI~c@HbJr@lJ`@|MrDfJlE~GxCdEvQ~IhCfDh@bIi@dGwB|D{GL{VqBqGcHcEeNGqGpGmHnQ
```

exactly as in your web (`google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_estimated_wp);`) decode:

```
-34.876070000000006,-56.152370000000005
-34.88199,-56.152420000000006
-34.883770000000005,-56.152680000000004
-34.885600000000004,-56.15285000000001
-34.88799,-56.15375
-34.889790000000005,-56.15478
-34.89123,-56.155550000000005
-34.89222,-56.158550000000005
-34.893980000000006,-56.159240000000004
...
```

[image: Decoded polyline]

So check your `android-maps-utils` in app `buld.gradle` file dependences and add latest [version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/) (0.5+ for now):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
}
```

or use custom `decodePoly()` method like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32838752/6950238) answer of [Marlon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527204/marlon) (actually its grabbed from [`android-map-utils`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/dba3b0d8a9657ebab8c67a4f50bd731437a229bc/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L436)) and gives the same result:

> ```
> private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
>
>   List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
>   int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
>   int lat = 0, lng = 0;
>
>   while (index < len) {
>       int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
>       do {
>           b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
>           result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
>           shift += 5;
>       } while (b >= 0x20);
>       int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
>       lat += dlat;
>
>       shift = 0;
>       result = 0;
>       do {
>           b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
>           result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
>           shift += 5;
>       } while (b >= 0x20);
>       int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
>       lng += dlng;
>
>       LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
>               (((double) lng / 1E5)));
>       poly.add(p);
>   }
>
>   return poly;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you Andrii, your answer guided me to the solution. The issue was that the json object obj.get("coordenadas").toString() adds some quotes to the string at the beginning and at the end and gave me this strange behaviour. I replaced it with obj.get("coordenadas").getAsString() and everything is fine now.